# Facebook Send api : not able to send a message using the phone number

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the recently release Send/Receive API for facebook messengers to build the chat bots referring to the documentation provided here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart

I have created a Facebook page and Facebook app and I am the admin of the app and have followed the steps mentioned in the documentation. I am trying to send a message to my own phone number to test it out using the send api.
In the documentation of the send api, its mentioned as `recipient.phone_number` or `recipient.id` must be set. the api works with the `recipient.id` but when I am using the `recipient.phone_number` field then the api throws an error.

Can anyone please help with using the send api with phone number?

**Sample request:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token="ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "recipient":{
        "phone_number ": "my phone number"
    }, 
    "message":{
        "text":"hello! how are you"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid keys \"phone_number \" were found in param \"recipient\".",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "GwOUYLfiR/A"
  }
}
```

My app is in the developer mode and my phone number has been added to my facebook profile and verified.

Comment: If it doesn’t work as the docs say – file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

As Tokenizer answered, you added a blank space in phone_number attribute name:
use "phone_number" instead of "phone_number ".

Comment: The blank space in the key was the issue  and also the phone number has to be in the format of `+1(212)222-2368`

Answer (score 1):

you have a blank space in phone_number attribute name.

Comment: do you mean literally the spaces in "my phone number" ? I hope that's a censorship on behalf of the OP